# How to transfer certain text files to a different directory based on the number of lines within these text files?

Tags: python

So I have a folder with lots of .txt files. I know the number of lines that are within each of the files and I have them in an array. What I want to do is only transfer the .txt files that have a certain number of lines into a separate folder, or delete the rest of the files that do not match the same number of lines.
The array that describes how many lines are there in each of the .txt files within this folder are like this:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 7, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 143, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 80, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 80, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 21, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 143, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 140, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 191, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 143, 1, 1, 21, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 173, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 187, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 191, 1, 1, 191, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 111, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 175, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 191, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 9, 16, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 190, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4]
```

What I want to do is separate out all the .txt files that have 191 lines within them and put them in a separate folder, or delete the rest that do not have 191 lines within the same folder. Please help!!!! thank you!

I got this order of array by doing the following:

```
>>> import os
>>> dir = '/'
>>> os.chdir(dir)
>>> ch1 = []
>>> for file in glob.glob('*'):
        f = open(file, "rU")
        f1 = f.readlines()
        new = len(f1[0].split(']['))
        ch1.append(new)

>>> ch1
```

and that's what gave me the array that tells me how many lines are there within every text file inside my directory.

Comment: Are you asking how to filter a list, or how to move and delete files? All of those topics are covered in standard documentation and tutorials (and StackOverflow questions). Please clarify your question.

Comment: How did you attain that order? Do you have a list of names of the files which correlate to those line counts?

Comment: os.listdir(path) returns a list of the files in the directory. Find out how long each is, then use shutil.move.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to use shutil.move?

Comment: @AryaIyer easy, check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) for it. It's dead simple, something like `shutil.move('/home/arya/yourfiles/foo.txt', '/home/arya/191onlyfiles')`. The directory `/home/arya/191onlyfiles` must already exist. You can get `/home/arya/yourfiles/foo.txt` from the `file` variable by using [`file.name`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.name).

Comment: so I did this: ch1 = []
>>> for filename in glob.glob('*'):
...     f = open(filename,"rU")
...     f1 = f.readlines()
...     new = len(f1[0].split(']['))
...     ch1.append(new)
...     for i in ch1:
...             if i == 191:
...                     shutil.move(filename, indir)
...             else:
...                     pass

Comment: And I get a random bunch of files that are moved to my new folder which is in indir = '/Users/arya/newfolder/' it doesn't follow the condition that if there are 191 lines in it, those are the ones I want to be moved.

Answer (score 0):

```
DESTPATH = "dest/i/nation/path/goes/here"
TARGET_LINES = 191

for filename in os.listdir():
    count = 0
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file:
            count += 1
    if count == TARGET_LINES:
        shutil.move(filename,DESTPATH)
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: listdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: @AryaIyer What version of Python are you on?

Comment: 2.7.5 version of python

Comment: @AryaIyer Ah. In Python3 it doesn't require an argument. You can use `os.listdir(os.getcwd())` to replicate that behavior. Probably even `os.listdir(".")` though I can't test it atm (I don't have Python2 on my work machine)